# Multiple simuntaniously overlapping IBcast

Tags: fortran, mpi

Since the collective communications of MPI don't have a flag parameter I was wondering if this can cause problems:

I have 2 MPI_communicators, that are not equal, but overlapping and I want to execute MPI_IBcast on both of them simuntaniously:

```
program main 
   use mpi
   implicit none
   integer :: comm1, comm2, ierr, me, req(2)
   integer :: color1(4) = [1,1,1,0]
   integer :: color2(4) = [0,1,1,1]
   integer :: a, b, new_me

   call MPI_Init(ierr) 

   call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, me, ierr)
   a = me - 1 
   b = me + 1

   call MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color1(me+1), me, comm1, ierr)
   call MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color2(me+1), me, comm2, ierr)

   CALL MPI_IBcast(a,1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, comm1, req(1), ierr)
   CALL MPI_IBcast(b,1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, comm2, req(2), ierr)

   call MPI_Waitall(2, req, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE, ierr)


   call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

   write (*,*) me, a, b
end program main
```

It worked fine on my local machine, but my question is: Is this guaranteed to work or do I have to use MPI_Bcast, rather than MPI_Ibcast?

Answer (score 2):

The communications use different communicators. As such it is fine. It doesn't matter that they both contain the same set of processes, they are different communicators and that is all that matters.

Comment: Maybe as a follow up: What about multiple IBcast  within one Communicator, which have the same root, but different data?

Comment: Ask as a new question with an example code and we'll take a look